# cron support in node.js App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a node.js app to App Engine with a cron job.  I added the cron.yaml file to the app (as instructed here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) and deployed, but the job never gets executed.

cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: test cron job
  url: /api/crontest
  schedule: every 1 mins
```

The endpoint exists in my app and I can hit it directly from the browser, but it never executes from the cron.

The only thing I see in the logs is an occasional `cron: unrecognized service`, but it does not correspond with the one minute frequency.

What am I missing?  Is cron supported in the platform?

Comment: maybe it should be `every 1 minutes`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml, `every 1 mins` should work.  That is the page I was following when setting up the cron job.  Unfortunately, the ultimate solution was on the previous page, and I missed it.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/yaml-configuration-files, I needed to run `gcloud preview app deploy cron.yaml` to deploy the cron.

Comment: Here's the documentation for node.js: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuration-files